# Staggered Grid Sytem

Tags: html, css, grid, 960.gs

I want to use 960.gs for a post layout on my website (4 columns). I like the ease of use, but it looks monotonous with the top and bottom of grid boxes lining up. Instead of the normal grid design, is there a way to make it more staggered like this site? [http://bygonebureau.com](http://bygonebureau.com/)

Notice how the bottom margins on the posts don't align.

Comment: That looks like a grid within a grid

Comment: I *think* you want [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) but I haven't actually used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular site uses [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to arrange articles like that. Grid systems like 960 dont allow for this because they rely on set 'rows', each of which has a clearfix applied so that they never overlap.

I would probably suggest you build the base layout of the site using a grid system, and simply follow the code examples in masonry for how to get that staggered boxes effect.

Comment: Thanks! Never have heard of it, but definitely will try!